# PDO connection doesn't return error when specified user doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, pdo, try-catch

I'm developing a configuration interface where the client has to specify the db parameters (host, user, password, db).

```
try{
  $c = new PDO('mysql:host='.$_POST['database_host'].';charset=utf-8', $_POST['database_user'], $_POST['database_password']);
  $c->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
  $c->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE,PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  $c->query("USE `".$_POST['database']."`;");
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    if(strstr($e->getMessage(),"[1045] Access denied for user '".$_POST['database_user']."'@'".$_POST['database_host']."' (using password: NO)"))
    {
        $errors[] = "This user requires a password.";
        $fields['database_password']['valid'] = false;
    }
    else if(strstr($e->getMessage(),"[1045] Access denied for user '".$_POST['database_user']."'@'".$_POST['database_host']."' (using password: YES)"))
    {
        $errors[] = "Wrong password or unexisting user.";
        $fields['database_password']['valid'] = false;
        $fields['database_user']['valid'] = false;
    }
    else echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

If I enter an existing user with wrong or no password the error is caught (the errors message is displayed "This user requires a password." or "Wrong password or unexisting user.").
But if I enter an unexisting user there is no error thrown just a warning

`Warning: PDO::query(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1044 Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mediatheque' in C:\wamp\www\mediatheque3\index.php on line 425`

and the script goes on I have no idea how to stop it and notify the user about the wrong username.

How should I handle that problem ?
Thank you.

Comment: If all you want is the script to stop executing, you could just add an 'exit()' in your code.

Comment: But on which condition ? There is just the warning displayed. No error is caught, I don't know how to test that the connection went okay.
if($c = new PDO(...)) returns true.

Comment: Might not be recommended, but in place of your 'echo' in the last line of your catch block. So instead of 'echo $e->getMessage()' you might use something such as 'exit($e->getMessage())'.

Comment: There is no error caught, except for the two cases I mentioned (existing user with & without password). Or maybe I didn't fully understand the try catch block, every error happening in the try block should raise an error, right? It's not considered an error but only a warning.

Comment: [Here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/trycatch.shtml) is an easy to understand article explaining try/catch blocks in JS. Basically they don't just 'handle errors better', but they allow the programmer to determine what the program should do if something fails. So in the case of your code above, it is not actually failing, but you're telling it just to print the error message from PDO. You're not actually connected to the database, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it makes sense because you set the `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` after creating the connection object so its too late.

Solution is to pass the attribute to the `PDO` constructor :

```
$attribute = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE,PDO::FETCH_OBJ
);
$c = new PDO('mysql:host='.$_POST['database_host'].';charset=utf-8',
                           $_POST['database_user'], $_POST['database_password'], 
                           $attribute);
```

Comment: Solved it ! I was so used to copy that block of code for the connection without paying attention that I forgot its purpose. Thank you for reminding me. The error is caught now.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the program continues to execute, even though the user is invalid is because you haven't exactly told it to stop executing. To do this, the simplest way is to add an 'exit()' statement where you want your program to stop executing. Here is your code below with some minor edits I made. It will print the error from PDO and exit if the PDO connection fails.

```
try{
  $c = new PDO('mysql:host='.$_POST['database_host'].';charset=utf-8',$_POST['database_user'], $_POST['database_password']);
  $c->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
  $c->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE,PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  $c->query("USE `".$_POST['database']."`;");
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    if(strstr($e->getMessage(),"[1045] Access denied for user '".$_POST['database_user']."'@'".$_POST['database_host']."' (using password: NO)"))
    {
        $errors[] = "This user requires a password.";
        $fields['database_password']['valid'] = false;
    }
    else if(strstr($e->getMessage(),"[1045] Access denied for user '".$_POST['database_user']."'@'".$_POST['database_host']."' (using password: YES)"))
    {
        $errors[] = "Wrong password or unexisting user.";
        $fields['database_password']['valid'] = false;
        $fields['database_user']['valid'] = false;
    }
    exit($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: It didn't go into the catch block because I set the attributes after the connection has been made so that's why that error wasn't caught, as @meda pointed out. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ahh I see now. I guess I didn't take notice of that right away.